# Regular expression for combination of alphanumeric and date in a text

Tags: java, regex, selenium, hp-uft

```
QA POLICY 02/07/2016
```

I want to validate the above expression. "QA POLICY" should be alphanumeric, and then the date should be validated.

I have used the below expression, and it is failing:

```
[A-Za-z0-9](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IG41V.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "QA POLICY" should be alphanumeric, and then the date should be validated.

I'm assuming you want an alphanumeric text to be validated followed by a date. You can use this regex:

```
^[\w ]*\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}
```

- `[\w ]*` allows any alphanumeric text as well as a space
- `\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}` allows a date in the format dd\mm\yyyy validating only the fact that they should all be numbers

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AYGQ43/2/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: "QA* POLICY 02/07/2016"  Is showing 1 match found..even though non alphanumeric is present in this text

Comment: That's because it considers 'POLICY 02/07/2016' as a match. You could add ^ in the beginning of the regex to fix this. ^ represents start of string so any symbol before date will reject it

Comment: Great! Updated the answer to include ^ at the beginning.